# Node with python as a child process always returns NativeBuffer

Tags: python, node.js, child-process

I have a Python test script which returns all detected audio devices.
Inside my Node script I use the following to communicate with the python script.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    pythonProcess = spawn('python', ['Audio.py']);

pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
   console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

pythonProcess.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});

pythonProcess.on('close', function (code) {
  console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});
```

Even when I print 'Hello World' in my Python script, it always returns the same 'NativeBuffer' and the output from the 'close' function. 
Why isn't stdout returning what my python script prints out?
I got it working once, but it seems to be broken now.

Comment: Does it help when you do `pythonProcess.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');`?

Comment: Nope, tried that already. Also `data.setEncoding('utf8')` returns the same.